# Why ingress-nginx-controller pod always establishes IPv4 TCP connection to endpoint?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

We have brought up k8s cluster on 2 VMs with dualstack feature enabled. Lets call them nodeA , nodeB. nodeA is master node, nodeB is worker node.

Following output gives info about cluster configuration

```
# ps -eaf | grep kubeapi
root     2593936 2593910  4 Mar16 ?        1-00:16:14 kube-apiserver --advertise-address=10.4.0.85 
--allow-privileged=true --authorization-mode=Node,RBAC --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt 
--enable-admission-plugins=NodeRestriction --enable-bootstrap-token-auth=true --etcd- 
cafile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --etcd-certfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd- 
client.crt --etcd-keyfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.key --etcd- 
servers=https://127.0.0.1:2379 --feature-gates=IPv6DualStack=true --insecure-port=0 --kubelet- 
client-certificate=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt --kubelet-client- 
key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.key --kubelet-preferred-address- 
types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname --proxy-client-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy- 
client.crt --proxy-client-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.key --requestheader- 
allowed-names=front-proxy-client --requestheader-client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy- 
ca.crt --requestheader-extra-headers-prefix=X-Remote-Extra- --requestheader-group-headers=X-Remote- 
Group --requestheader-username-headers=X-Remote-User --secure-port=6443 --service-account- 
issuer=https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local --service-account-key- 
file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.pub --service-account-signing-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.key -- 
service-cluster-ip-range=10.244.1.0/24,2001:db8:1234:5678:8:2::/112 --tls-cert- 
file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt --tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.key
```

We have created ClusterIP service apple-service and ingress-nginx-controller nodePort service as shown below

```
# kubectl describe svc apple-service
Name:              apple-service
Namespace:         default
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=apple
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  PreferDualStack
IP Families:       IPv4,IPv6
IP:                10.244.1.104
IPs:               10.244.1.104,2001:db8:1234:5678:8:2:0:6294
Port:              <unset>  5678/TCP
TargetPort:        5678/TCP
Endpoints:         10.244.2.150:5678,10.244.2.151:5678
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>

# kubectl describe svc ingress-nginx-controller -n ingress-nginx
Name:                     ingress-nginx-controller
Namespace:                ingress-nginx
Labels:                   app.kubernetes.io/component=controller
                          app.kubernetes.io/instance=ingress-nginx
                          app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                          app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
                          app.kubernetes.io/version=0.44.0
                      helm.sh/chart=ingress-nginx-3.23.0
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 
app.kubernetes.io/component=controller,app.kubernetes.io/instance=ingress- 
nginx,app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
Type:                     NodePort
IP Family Policy:         PreferDualStack
IP Families:              IPv4,IPv6
IP:                       10.244.1.4
IPs:                      10.244.1.4,2001:db8:1234:5678:8:2:0:6033
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               http/TCP
NodePort:                 http  31003/TCP
Endpoints:                10.244.2.144:80
Port:                     https  443/TCP
TargetPort:               https/TCP
NodePort:                 https  31801/TCP
Endpoints:                10.244.2.144:443
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>


# kubectl describe ep apple-service
Name:         apple-service
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  endpoints.kubernetes.io/last-change-trigger-time: 2021-04-01T12:53:37Z
Subsets:
Addresses:          10.244.2.150,10.244.2.151
 NotReadyAddresses:  <none>
 Ports:
  Name     Port  Protocol
  ----     ----  --------
  <unset>  5678  TCP

Events:  <none>
```

We have created following ingress resource.

```
# kubectl describe ingress
Name:             example-ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:          10.11.0.58
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *
          /apple   apple-service:5678 (10.244.2.150:5678,10.244.2.151:5678)
Annotations:  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
Events:       <none>
```

We have created 2 pods behind ClusterIP service , which have dual-stack addresses.

```
# kubectl describe pod apple-app-1
Name:         apple-app-1
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         ccd-focal-clus1-2/10.11.0.58
Start Time:   Thu, 01 Apr 2021 12:38:56 +0000
Labels:       app=apple
Annotations:  cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 10.244.2.150/32
          cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 10.244.2.150/32,2001:db8:1234:5678:8:3:0:3295/128
Status:       Running
IP:           10.244.2.150
IPs:
 IP:  10.244.2.150
 IP:  2001:db8:1234:5678:8:3:0:3295
 ...

# kubectl describe pod apple-app-2
Name:         apple-app-2
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         ccd-focal-clus1-2/10.11.0.58
Start Time:   Thu, 01 Apr 2021 12:53:34 +0000
Labels:       app=apple
Annotations:  cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 10.244.2.151/32
          cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 10.244.2.151/32,2001:db8:1234:5678:8:3:0:3296/128
Status:       Running
IP:           10.244.2.151
IPs:
  IP:  10.244.2.151
  IP:  2001:db8:1234:5678:8:3:0:3296
```

The ingress-nginx-controller pod details

```
# kubectl describe pods ingress-nginx-controller-67897c9494-s4fkw -n ingress-nginx
Name:         ingress-nginx-controller-67897c9494-s4fkw
Namespace:    ingress-nginx
Priority:     0
Node:         ccd-focal-clus1-2/10.11.0.58
Start Time:   Wed, 31 Mar 2021 14:53:49 +0000
Labels:       app.kubernetes.io/component=controller
          app.kubernetes.io/instance=ingress-nginx
          app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
          pod-template-hash=67897c9494
Annotations:  cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 10.244.2.144/32
          cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 10.244.2.144/32,2001:db8:1234:5678:8:3:0:328f/128
Status:       Running
IP:           10.244.2.144
IPs:
 IP:           10.244.2.144
 IP:           2001:db8:1234:5678:8:3:0:328f
```

nodeA (master) ifconfig output as follows:

```
ens3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.11.0.137  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.11.0.255
    inet6 2001:db8:100:c1::287  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
    inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fed5:1b32  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether fa:16:3e:d5:1b:32  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 350743  bytes 51111859 (51.1 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 4874839  bytes 386319524 (386.3 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens4: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.4.0.85  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.4.0.255
    inet6 2001:db8:100:a1::1a6  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
    inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fe53:adc5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether fa:16:3e:53:ad:c5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 6942419  bytes 1695386713 (1.6 GB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 8330231  bytes 2487914325 (2.4 GB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

nodeB (worker) ifconfig output as follows:

```
ens3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.11.0.58  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.11.0.255
    inet6 2001:db8:100:c1::12a  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
    inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fe6e:35da  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether fa:16:3e:6e:35:da  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 134737  bytes 15951676 (15.9 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 153842  bytes 35255446 (35.2 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens4: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.4.0.45  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.4.0.255
    inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fe15:91ba  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    inet6 2001:db8:100:a1::9  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
    ether fa:16:3e:15:91:ba  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 6918097  bytes 3530410872 (3.5 GB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 5392656  bytes 638310030 (638.3 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

When we execute "curl -LO  http://[2001:db8:100:c1::12a]:31003/apple" , we see that IPv6 TCP connection is established with ingress-nginx-controller address 2001:db8:1234:5678:8:3:0:328f . From ingress-nginx-controller pod to backend pod , IPv4 TCP connection is establised. i.e 10.244.2.144 --> 10.244.2.151 (apple-app-2).

[image: Below picture shows the tcpdump output taken on ingress-nginx-controller pod.]

[image]

Comment: What version of Kubernetes do you have ?
Do you have Kubernetes on bare-metal or Managed Kubernetes Service ? 
Which CNI are you using ?

Comment: I have installed 1.21-beta k8s version. Its not bare-metal , but have installed k8s cluster on 2 VMs. (one master , one worker node). I am using calico CNI for primary networking.

Answer (score 0):

As you can find in the [Validate IPv4/IPv6 dual-stack documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/network/validate-dual-stack/#validate-services) - the order of `ipFamilies` in the `.spec.ipFamilies` array matters.

> Kubernetes will assign both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses (as this cluster has dual-stack enabled) and select the .spec.ClusterIP from the list of .spec.ClusterIPs based on the address family of the first element in the .spec.ipFamilies array.

You specified `IPv4` as the first array element in `.spec.ipFamilies`, therefore Kubernetes assigned a cluster IP for this Service from the IPv4 range.

```
# kubectl describe svc apple-service
Name:              apple-service
...
IP Family Policy:  PreferDualStack
IP Families:       IPv4,IPv6
IP:                10.244.1.104
```

Changing the order of `ipFamilies` will solve this problem:

```
spec:
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv6
  - IPv4
```

---

I've created a simple example to illustrate how it works.

I have a single `app-1` `Deployment` exposed using the `ClusterIP` service:

```
# kubectl get deploy,pod,svc
NAME                    READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/app-1   1/1     1            1           52m

NAME                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/app-1-5d9ccdb595-nrljs   1/1     Running   0          52m

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP            EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/app-1        ClusterIP   2001:db8:42:1::f4a0   <none>        80/TCP    19m

# kubectl describe ing
Name:             example-ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:          10.0.0.5
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *           
              /app-1   app-1:80 ([2001:db8:42:cd:2fba:8d83:9906:4d8f]:80)

# kubectl get svc ingress-nginx-controller -n ingress-nginx
NAME                       TYPE       CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx-controller   NodePort   10.96.60.120   <none>        80:31072/TCP,443:30408/TCP   133m
```

Let's take a look at the manifest of the `app-1` `Service`:
**NOTE:** `IPv6` is the first element in the `.spec.ipFamilies` array.

```
# cat svc.yml 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: app-1
  name: app-1
  namespace: default
spec:
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv6    
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: PreferDualStack
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: app-1
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
```

We can check if it works as expected:
**NOTE:**
It doesn't matter if we run `curl public_ipv4_address:31072/app-1` or `curl [public_ipv6_address]:31072/app-1`.

```
# kubectl exec -it app-1-5d9ccdb595-nrljs -- bash
root@app-1-5d9ccdb595-nrljs:/# tcpdump -n 'port 80'
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
11:02:06.918674 IP6 2001:db8:42:cd:2fba:8d83:9906:4d8e.54406 > 2001:db8:42:cd:2fba:8d83:9906:4d8f.80: Flags [S], seq 3544899375, win 64860, options [mss 1380,sackOK,TS val 2211355791 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
11:02:06.918705 IP6 2001:db8:42:cd:2fba:8d83:9906:4d8f.80 > 2001:db8:42:cd:2fba:8d83:9906:4d8e.54406: Flags [S.], seq 1030071611, ack 3544899376, win 64296, options [mss 1380,sackOK,TS val 1923799370 ecr 2211355791,nop,wscale 7], length 0
11:02:06.918736 IP6 2001:db8:42:cd:2fba:8d83:9906:4d8e.54406 > 2001:db8:42:cd:2fba:8d83:9906:4d8f.80: Flags [.], ack 1, win 507, options [nop,nop,TS val 2211355791 ecr 1923799370], length 0
11:02:06.918787 IP6 2001:db8:42:cd:2fba:8d83:9906:4d8e.54406 > 2001:db8:42:cd:2fba:8d83:9906:4d8f.80: Flags [P.], seq 1:353, ack 1, win 507, options [nop,nop,TS val 2211355791 ecr 1923799370], length 352: HTTP: GET / HTTP/1.1
11:02:06.918794 IP6 2001:db8:42:cd:2fba:8d83:9906:4d8f.80 > 2001:db8:42:cd:2fba:8d83:9906:4d8e.54406: Flags [.], ack 353, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 1923799370 ecr 2211355791], length 0
11:02:06.919421 IP6 2001:db8:42:cd:2fba:8d83:9906:4d8f.80 > 2001:db8:42:cd:2fba:8d83:9906:4d8e.54406: Flags [P.], seq 1:240, ack 353, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 1923799371 ecr 2211355791], length 239: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
11:02:06.919455 IP6 2001:db8:42:cd:2fba:8d83:9906:4d8e.54406 > 2001:db8:42:cd:2fba:8d83:9906:4d8f.80: Flags [.], ack 240, win 506, options [nop,nop,TS val 2211355792 ecr 1923799371], length 0
```

Comment: Yes it explained partially. But i also found one configuration which explains it completely. https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#service-upstream